# jQuery Drag/Drop Example: Ordered List does not look like ordered list at the destination

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, html-lists

I can drag and drop, it works very good. But at the destination place the ordered list does not work properly. It should look like a ordered-list not like a pile. The destination box should grow with new element, but it does not work too.

Where is my mistake? Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/QJ54x/

That's the jQuery-Code so far:

```
$( init );
function init () {          
    $('.draggable1').draggable ({ 
        containment: "#ddSurvexFormDragDropArea",
        scope: "d1",
        stop: draggable1Stop,
        helper: "clone",

    });

    $('#droppable1').droppable({
        scope: "d1",
        accept: ".draggable1",
        hoverClass: "droppable1HoverClass",
        drop: droppable1Drop,
    });
}

function draggable1Stop(event,ui) {
    // alert ('draggable1Stop');
    // $(this).remove();
    ui.helper.clone().appendTo($(this).parent());
    $(this).remove();
}

function droppable1Drop (event, ui) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it, here is the answer (another simplified example):

http://jsfiddle.net/cKs5u/

That's the corresponding part:

```
$( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );

    }
})
```

given by example from jquery-api online.